# How do I catch this error for an undefined property of an object?

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have a search method that utilized an API and returns a list of matches along with properties such as 'id' and 'title' but only some of these have a title. When there is no title present, I get an error of undefined.

I have tried plenty of if = undefined variations but everything comes back with this error:

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

```
           <% if (results.length == 0){ %>
              <h1>No Matching Results</h1>
           <% } else if(typeof results[i].id !== "undefined"){ %>
              <a href="/second/<%= results[i].id %>">
                 <%= results[i].name %>
                 <% if(results[i].known_for[0].title) { %>
                    Known For: <%= results[i].known_for[0].title %>
                 <% } else { %>
                    Known For: Nothing
                 <% } %>
             </a>
            <% } %>
```

I just want it to output a title if it is provided and then have an else statement if it is not.

Comment: `if (results[i].known_for && results[i].known_for.length > 0)`

Comment: If a list is returned seems that you should be looping, unless you've excluded that. I see that you are only checking if id is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```html
           <% if (results.length == 0){ %>
              <h1>No Matching Results</h1>
           <% } else if(typeof results[i].id !== "undefined"){ %>
              <a href="/second/<%= results[i].id %>">
                 <%= results[i].name %>
                 <% if(results[i].known_for[0].title !== undefined || results[i].known_for[0].title !== "undefined" || results[i].known_for[0].title !== null) { %>
                    Known For: <%= results[i].known_for[0].title %>
                 <% } else { %>
                    Known For: Nothing
                 <% } %>
             </a>
            <% } %>
```